# Efficient way to reformat or split a string that has JSON records

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I have this string that consists of a set of JSON entries concatenated together like the following

```
val docs = """
  {"name": "Bilbo Baggins", "age": 50}{"name": "Gandalf", "age": 1000}{"name": "Thorin", "age": 195}{"name": "Balin", "age": 178}{"name": "Kíli", "age": 77} """
```

I'd like to convert it to something like this (basically a comma after each record):

```
{"name": "Bilbo Baggins", "age": 50}, {"name": "Gandalf", "age": 1000}, {"name": "Thorin", "age": 195}
```

So that I can save these records to my mongodb collection.
The way it is done on the SparkConnector documentation was by using **split("[\r\n]+")** which matches linebreaks. That approach is efficient but not what I want because I am using the **circe Library** to format JSON records and this library adds linebreaks to the Lists in these records and thus the string would be broken by the above split.

What I'm doing now is that when forming the **docs** string, I'm adding **"@#@"** between each two entries and later splitting them using this expression.

**is this the right way to do this? or is there a smarter way? it is possible to create a regular expression that would match the brackets and their contents and be used to split the string and return the result the way I want it?**

Comment: Why cannot you insert ", " instead of "@#@"?

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it answered your question.

Comment: ofcourse, I think it should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the commas to make valid json using regex like this:

```
val s = """{"name": "Bilbo Baggins", "age": 50}{"name": "Gandalf", "age": 1000}"""
s.replaceAll("""(\{.*?\})""", """$1,""").dropRight(1)
```

Output:

```
res151: String = "{"name": "Bilbo Baggins", "age": 50},{"name": "Gandalf", "age": 1000}"
```

The `\{` matches a literal bracket, the `.*?` does a non-greedy match of any characters before the next `\}` and the `(...)` is a capture group which we refer to in the replace string as $1.

Comment: Why not replace `}{` with `},{`